# Garbage collector stops gathering objects from eden after Spring Batch job initiated

Tags: java, docker, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, spring-batch

GC does collect object with intervals as expected. However, after first spring batch job is finished, the following happens:

1. Memory usage increases unexpetedly like 10x of my expectations;
2. GC stops doing its job automatically, but responds to jcmd .jar GC.run and frees the memory.

Was thinking about memory leak so that gc can not collect the objects, but I can trigger it using jcmd <jar-app-name>.jar GC.run. Thus, I am confused. GC actually can collect, but why it is not doing its job even when app is out of memory.

Also, I use excel poi library's PoiItemReader class to read an excel file.

I think it has something to do with following:

1. cmd run java app command arguments;
2. Apache poi library reading the excel at once, not piece by piece kind of killing the batch concept;

If anyone has idea about the issue, please comment.

The app is running as container from image build using the following dockerfile commands:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-11:latest
COPY build/libs/*.jar /app/app.jar
WORKDIR /app/
CMD ["java", "-XX:+UseContainerSupport", "-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please give your problem statement